# Postgresql: add 24 hours on a timestamp

Tags: postgresql

Hi i have to add 24 hours on a timestamp converted from a string in postgres db.

here my code:

```
select to_timestamp(timestamp_start, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS.US') + interval '24 hour' as tstamp from tablename
```

the query works but it adds two 0 at the end of the timestamp: "2017-05-23 17:35:13.105867+00"

why and how to solve it?

Comment: It's the timezone

Comment: cast to timestamp ?..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`+00` meant it is timestamp with timezone and your client timezone is UTC.

If you dont want those **+00** on the screen, cast it to `timestamp without timezone`, eg:

```
t=# select now();
              now
-------------------------------
 2017-05-23 09:04:46.105322+00
(1 row)

Time: 0.690 ms
t=# select now()::timestamp;
            now
----------------------------
 2017-05-23 09:04:51.849522
(1 row)

Time: 0.537 ms
```

So for query in original post it would be:

```
select (to_timestamp(timestamp_start, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS.US') + interval '24 hour')::timestamp as tstamp 
from tablename
```

Comment: Thanks for answer. select to_timestamp(timestamp_start, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS.US') at time zone 'UTC' + interval '24 hour' as tstamp from tablename. Could this be a good solution?